# customise perforce change number

Tags: repository, perforce, p4v

Is it possible to customize perforce change number. I heared that we can do it. I checked on line but didnt find any solution.

For example trying to get change number as power of two, or multiple of 10 etc. Is this possible. Right now i get a complete random number.

Thanks

Comment: Change numbers are sequential, not random.

Comment: It is at least somewhat possible (e.g., by forcing the change counter prior to creating your changelist), but why? What good would it do?

Comment: I don't know the benefits, but it looks like a challenging problem which has solution. so curious to learn how to achieve it.